# Why does OpenStack distinguish images from snapshots?

Tags: snapshot, openstack

Usually, https://serverfault.com/a/268727/126950:

- snapshot = an exact capture of what a volume looked like at a particular moment in time, including all it's data.
- image = a total snapshot of a system (doesn't save the user data)

However, http://docs.openstack.org/folsom/openstack-ops/content/snapsnots.html says

> In OpenStack, an instance snapshot is an image. The only difference
>   between an image that you upload directly to glance and an image you
>   create by snapshot is that an image created by snapshot has additional
>   properties in the glance database.

So why does OpenStack distinguish images from snapshots?

Comment: actually i think for organization purposes on dashboard, it's a good idea to distinguish snapshot from image at least on GUI, otherwise in a live environment you got a long list of images some of which are snapshots..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no meaningful difference between the two, and it's only the OpenStack dashboard that makes a distinction between between images and snaphots. I submitted this issue as a [UI bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1140760) a while back, and it has been [fixed](https://review.openstack.org/30064) in the upcoming (havana) release of OpenStack.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Short of upgrading Openstack, is there any way to make a *snapshot* show up as an *image* in the UI? Or otherwise "convert" a snapshot to an image?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment on JDS's Question directly, but here is the answer:
You have to download the snapshot and create an image out of it via glance, so something like this:

```
source openrc
glance list-images #find your snapshots ID
glance image-download "snapshot-ID" --file "some name".qcow2 #without the ""
glance image-create --name "desired image name" --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --min-disk="size of the virtual disk of the snapshot" --is-public True --is-protected True --file "some-name".qcow2 #again without the ""
```